# What is the syntax for document.body.style.backgroundColor?

Tags: javascript

I am a JavaScript newbie. I have the following code and it is behaving very strangely.  What it is *supposed* to do is originally set the background color to red, then cycle through a series of background colors after an alert dialogue is cleared.  Color names are currently in string formats, but the same behavior results if I use the hex IDs.

Usually, when the page is loaded, it starts off coloring the body red like it is supposed to. The first alert clear sometimes changes the background to orange, sometimes not, then there is no change as the next dialogues (yellow, green, blue, indigo, black) are cleared until the last color change, which sometimes takes and sometimes doesn't.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Color Flasher</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function color1() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }

    function color2() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
    }

    function color3() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }

    function color4() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }

    function color5() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }

    function color6() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'indigo';
    }

    function color7() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    }

    function color8() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'violet';
    }

    color1();

    alert("ready for another color? - orange");
    color2();

    alert("ready for another color? - yellow");
    color3();

    alert("ready for another color? - green");
    color4();

    alert("ready for another color? - blue");
    color5();

    alert("ready for another color? - indigo");
    color6();

    alert("ready for another color? - black");
    color7();

    alert("ready for another color? - violet");
    color8();
</script>

<center>
<h1>Color Flasher<br></h1>
</center>
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain where I'm getting the syntax wrong?

Comment: works every time for me but it looks like it could be that the document isn't fully loaded.  Place your `<style>` element at the end of body or in a document.ready kind of structure.

Comment: Internet Explorer issue, works on firefox or chrome

Comment: Ahh, you are right rob.  IE doesn't like it at all.  didn't think to test in the other browsers.  any thoughts on best way to make it work in IE?  will try playing with what Joseph suggested...

Comment: Works on IE9 also. I just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try placing your `<script>` in the `<head>` or if you really want your script in the body tag, you should place before the closing `</body>` tag.

FYI it works fine on my side. Tested on JSFiddle and they automatically place the `<script>` in the body tag.